# jQuery keypress event for a form that's a resulf of an ajax call

Tags: jquery, events, keypress

Clicking a link in my page submits an ajax request and loads the response in a modal dialog window. That response contains a form with id 'ModalForm'. What I am trying to achieve is to prevent the default form behavior of the 'Enter' key for this specific form and replace it with execution of a JS function that I wrote. Unfortunately I can't get it to work nor I receive an alert message. Here's my code:

```
jQuery(function (){
    jQuery('#ModalForm').keypress(function(e){
        alert(e.keyCode);
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            modalWindowSubmit();
        }
    });

    jQuery('#ModalForm').on('keypress', (function() {
        alert('hi');
    });

});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to execute this piece of JS in the callback of loading `#ModalForm`, not at document ready. Or either use `.live()` instead of `.on()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind the event on the form in the "success" of the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

You have to use KeyUp - keycode is not known at keypress time

```
  jQuery(function (){
   jQuery('#ModalForm').keyup(function(e){
    alert(e.keyCode);
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        modalWindowSubmit();
    }
});
```

or

```
  jQuery(document).on('keyup', '#ModalForm', (function(e) {
    alert(e.KeyCode);
  });
```

.on is typically used to bind elements to events when the element is created dynamically , if that is not the case the first option will work just fine